# How to synchronise an Ubuntu and Windows desktop

Tags: windows, xubuntu, sync

I'm total newbie about Ubuntu. Some time ago I have installed Xubuntu 14.04 LTS distribution of Ubuntu.  At my university I have seen Linux configured with Windows so that they use the same of desktop. I would like to configure ubuntu to use the same desktop with windows. I don't mean to use remote desktop or change appearance of desktop. I mean exactly the same desktop in a sense of files and shortcuts. When I edit a text file in windows this affects on the same file in ubuntu desktop. Similarly I want the /home folder synchronized with "my documents" folder in windows. I know it's possible because computers at my university are synchronized that how I said.

I have read something about Ubuntu-one but I got lost in the amount of information and do not really know what it is and how it would help me.

I have searched entire internet for answer but all i found it's tutorial to set the systems with remote desktop.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Do you need that at the moment sync or to be synced every interval of time? or maybe you want to change your linux home folder, desktop folder to be the same as windows folders not having to copy files (sync them)

Comment: They're probably using the same storage for both Ubuntu and Windows. You can do that locally on Ubuntu as well, because NTFS is supported in Ubuntu. You'll probably mount the NTFS partition and then do a lot of bind-mounts to link the right directories from Windows to Ubuntu. It's not exactly difficult, but it requires some work.

Comment: Ok fine, so I want to have the same desktop and home folder as windows's. You say something  about partitioning and bind-mounts but how to do it exactly. Is there step by step solution or tutorial somewhere in internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount ntfs discs on startup, ntfs-config will help with that, then delete your desktop folder, make link (alt )  at home and name it desktop, same approach with document's.

I advice you only make link to windows desktop on Linux desktop to avoid problems.

Comment: When I delete desktop folder, it returns back in few seconds, itself.

Comment: Weird, try replacing in this file then: ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Comment: Ok, I finally have a files from windows desktop on ubuntu desktop, but when I try to remove something from desktop i have following problem "Unable to find or create trash directory".

Comment: You may need to add trash directory, use Google on that problem, i cant be your personal researcher, or you could shift-delete to delete the files permanently.